# Passivation capable beans must satisfy passivation capable dependencies

Tags: jsf, cdi, serializable, omnifaces, view-scope

I'm having a little issue with OmniFaces's Viewscoped. Even with my Managedbean implementing Serializable, I'm receiving the error below:

> Passivation capable beans must satisfy passivation capable dependencies.

With some research, I found some answers about the this problem but with no success. I resolved my problem serializing my other class that I'm injecting with CDI.

Is it really necessary my other classes implementing Serializable to Inject in my Managedbean?

Environment
- WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.2
- Apache MyFaces 2.0.2
- OmniFaces 1.7
- PrimeFaces 5.0

My Class:

```
public class AgrupamentoAcoRN{

@Inject
public TbSiglaAcoAgrupadaDAO dao;

public void insereDados(TbSiglaAcoAgrupada tbSiglaAcoAgrupada) throws BancoDeDadosException{
    dao.insereRegistro(tbSiglaAcoAgrupada);
}
}
```

My Bean:

```
@Named("agrupamentoAcoMb")
@ViewScoped
public class AgrupamentoAcoMB implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private AgrupamentoAcoRN rn;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All fields of a Serializable java class should be serializable, hence every field in your viewScoped bean should be serializable also.

Your problem have nothing to do with Omnifaces